# How would you finger this arpeggio on guitar?

Tags: fingering, improvisation, classical-guitar, fingerstyle-guitar, arpeggios

What would be your approach for right-hand-fingering this arpeggio pattern with classical guitar or fingerstyle technique (no pick)?

[image]

I've tried out several approaches, being this one the most functional  (for me):

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us what speed it is to be played, and show the bar(s) after the arpeggio? I've found that for most arpeggio's, most share around 90% of the fingering, because, well. guitar, not every theoretical possibility is acutally feasible. The other 10% are personal preferences, i.e. what works best for _you_. And a lot of it depends on the speed, and what comes after.

Comment: Hi Willem. Thanks for your interests. I'm practicing this kind of arpeggio as a way of exploring the fretboard and gaining resources for improvising. So, my objective isn't to play it as fast as16th at 150 bpm but rather to find right hand fingering that can serve me as a model for fingering other similar arpeggios also with the aim of using them in improvisation scenarios

Comment: Ah okay. Then mostly it will come down to personal preference. I agree with @user1079505 that ending with the thumb twice is probably going to break you up when playing at speed. I'd finish either with an m-i or i-p combo.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities, depending on what are your goals (articulation, speed, ...?)

For most people, when changing strings downwards (so as in the second measure in your example) it's more convenient to change fingers towards the thumb. E.g. you play the last note on first string in the first measure with *m* and then the first note in the second measure on second string with *a*. You may consider changing *a* with *i*, for example.

Playing the very last two notes with thumb might be more more difficult.

Thumb may sound a bit different from the other fingers, so you may want to be more consistent in placing the thumb on strong beats in the first measure.

Finally, there is some possibility of using open strings in this example, but this also affects the sound.

Answer (score 0):

You can play it using a sweep technique with a thumb finger or using all other fingers on the first strings. Or you can play it with a pick. 5/5 can be played with one or two left hand fingers.